# Scala Spark - udf Column is not supported

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

I am trying to use a `udf` that would be the equivalent of:

`df.select(when(col("abc").isNotNull and col("abc") =!= "" and col("age") <= 18, 1).otherwise(0).alias("something"))`

I declared the `udf` like:

```
//return Int 0 or 1 if conditions are true 
val myudf_x = udf((col_name: String, col_value: String, num: Int) => {
  when(col_name.isNotNull and col_name =!= "" and col_value < num, 1).otherwise(0)

})
```

usage:

```
  df.select(
  "col_abc",
  myudf(col("col_abc"), col("age"), 18).alias("something")
)
```

but I get an **error**:

> Schema for type org.apache.spark.sql.Column is not supported

I've also tried the udf with `String` types instead of `column` type

What is the issue?

thanks

Answer (score 8):

A simple distinction:

- Expressions operate on SQL types (`Columns`).
- `udfs` operate on external (Scala) types.

If you want a function using expression DSL:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Column

// You can use function:
// def f(col_name: Column, col_value: Column, num: Column) = ???
// I used closure syntax to highlight difference in types
val f: (Column, Column, Column) => Column = 
  (col_name: Column, col_value: Column, num: Column) =>  when(
    col_name.isNotNull and col_name =!= "unknown" and col_value < num, 
    1
  ).otherwise(0)
```

otherwise:

```
val g: UserDefinedFunction = udf(
  (col_name: String, col_value: String, num: Int) => {
    if (col_name != null && col_name != "unknown" && col_value < num) 1 else 0
  }
)
```

but in current form the udf won't type check (`col_value` is a `String` and `num` is `Int` - they cannot be compared with `<`).

Maybe you wanted `col_value.cast("int") < num` / `col_value.toInt < num`?